# Reverse a number depending on the total number of digits

Tags: javascript, number-manipulation

Is there a built-in function in javascript to reverse a number depending on the total number? if no how to implement it?

i.e.

```
number = 2;
total_number = 10;
__________________
answer = 9;
```

```
reverse(2, 10) // returns 9
```

since:

```
 1  == 10
[2  ==  9]
 3  ==  8
 4  ==  7
 5  ==  6
 6  ==  5
 7  ==  4
 8  ==  3
 9  ==  2
 10 ==  1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
function (num, total) {
    return total - num + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't this work:

```
total - number + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not:

```
Total_number - number + 1
```